# javascript how to delete a certain part of string?

Tags: javascript, string, cookies, replace

I got this string from my cookies (example) :

```
Cookies = "link1=whatever; link2=whatever; delete1=true; link3=whatever; delete3=true; link4=whatever;"
```

I want to delete the last part of the string that starts with delete and ends with ";" OR "" (nothing, sting end). In this example i want   --> delete3=true; <-- that part to be deleted

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
Cookies = Cookies.split(';');
var i = Cookies.length,
    r = /^ *delete\d+=/;
while (--i >= 0) {
    if (r.test(Cookies[i])) {
        Cookies.splice(i, 1);
        Cookies = Cookies.join(';');
        break;
    } 
}
```

A shorter way :

```
Cookies = Cookies.replace(
    /; *delete\d+=[^;]*(?!.*; *delete\d+=)/, ''
);
```

Even simpler (based on [Goran.it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798130/1636522)) :

```
Cookies = Cookies.replace(/(.*;) *delete\d+=.*?;/, '$1');
```

Feel free to ask for details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple regex solution:

```
var Cookies = "link1=whatever; link2=whatever; delete1=true; link3=whatever; delete3=true; link4=whatever;";
var fixed = Cookies.replace(/(.*)(\s?delete.*?;)(.*)$/, '$1$3');

// fixed is now: "link1=whatever; link2=whatever; delete1=true; link3=whatever;  link4=whatever;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
Cookies = "link1=whatever; link2=whatever; delete1=true; link3=whatever; delete3=true; link4=whatever;";

aa = Cookies.split(';');

for (_i = 0, _len = aa.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  a = aa[_i];
  if (a.trim().search(/^delete/) !== -1) deleters = aa.indexOf(a);
}

aa.splice(deleters, 1);

Cookies = aa.join(';');
```

CoffeeScript:

```
Cookies = "link1=whatever; link2=whatever; delete1=true; link3=whatever; delete3=true; link4=whatever;"
aa=Cookies.split(';')
for a in aa
    deleters=aa.indexOf(a) if a.trim().search(/^delete/)!=-1
aa.splice(deleters, 1)
Cookies = aa.join(';')
```